# Spoiler markup doesn't completely hide the text in Chrome 14

Tags: support, spoilers, design

The rendering of spoilers on beta sites doesn't completely hide the text on Google Chrome 14.0.835.35 beta (Linux). It doesn't happen under previous Chrome versions (13 and below).

[image: What is the background of God's Demon by Wayne Barlowe?]

I have no idea whether this can be fixed in the Stack Exchange styling or it's a bug in Chrome or if it can be tuned in a user script.

Comment: There's also no way to read spoilered text on my iPad. I dunno if that can be fixed or not.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris [Can't see spoilers on touchscreen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75656) :( And I didn't tag my question [tag:bug] on purpose: Chrome beta isn't supported, and the bug doesn't appear on stable versions.

Comment: Gotcha. And it sucks that they aren't even trying to fix that bug for iOS. This site looks great on my ipad with that exception.

Comment: @Gilles: Shouldn't this be posted on MSO?

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto [Don't make Rebecca cry!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232)

Comment: @Gilles: Good thing it wasn't the first post...

Answer (score 4):

Need I remind you that we officially do not support beta and unreleased browsers? :)

If this is still an issue when Chrome 14 is released, let us know.